# MACOS ~/.zshrc shell isn't recognizing command

Tags: shell, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, macos-ventura

```
➜  ~ nano ~/.zshrc

zsh: command not found: nano

➜  ~ pwd

/Users/uttamkhan

➜  ~ ls

zsh: command not found: ls

➜  ~ exec $SHELL

/etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale
/Users/uttamkhan/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/Users/uttamkhan/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh:29: command not found: git
/Users/uttamkhan/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:115: command not found: rm
compdump:138: command not found: mv
/Users/uttamkhan/.zshrc:104: command not found: pyenv
```

Comment: You probably messed up the `PATH` environment variable or `path` array.

Comment: You just show us that your PATH/path is obviously wrong. Why don't you simply fix it by setting it to  a reasonable value?

Comment: fyi this is on the wrong site - consider moving to [apple.se]. Stack Overflow is for programming q&a.